# Data At Varying Granularity

Tags: machine-learning, classification, multilevel-analysis

I'm sorry for asking such a simple question, but for some reason it is throwing me off. By "granularity" I mean level of the data. For example, say in the classic example of spam classification you have data at the email level (IP address of sender, email extension of sender, time of day sent etc..) and data at the individual word level.
So, the prediction you want to make is at the email level, but you have data at the word granularity for each email as well. So, at the email level, do you view each possible word as a categorical variable that takes on {0,1} if its present in a given email? So, say you wanted to take a shot at modeling with logistic regression, does this leave with like 100,000 coded variables (if your dictionary has 100,000 words) for each email?
How does this model stay tractable? Especially if the email level data is significant? Would that data get overshadowed by fitting 100,000 dummy variables?

I'm more asking about this scenario in general, I know that I could just google methods of email classification.  I figure this comes up whenever you are working in a relational database and you want to make a prediction at the granularity of table A, but have a lower granularity table that joins on A.primary_key = B.foreign_key.